# Python: signal.pause() equivalent on Windows

Tags: python, windows, signals

I have my main application thread that spawns 2 threads and I catch SIGINT in my main thread to quit them nicely.
On linux, I'm using `signal.pause()` and it works perfectly.

**What is the best way to implement signal.pause() on Windows?**

My ugly solution is:

```
my_queue.get(True, averylongtime)
```

And put something in my_queue in my signal handler. Note that if I don't specify a timeout, SIGINT is not caught. But I wonder if there's a better solution.

Thank you

Comment: How are you generating the SIGINT?  If it's just a <CTRL>+C from the keyboard then you could trap KeyboardInterrupt.  Otherwise it might be a case of raising a Win32 event.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not beautiful you can do something like this

```py
import os, platform

match platform.system():
    case 'Linux':
        signal.pause()   
    case 'Windows':
         os.system('pause')
    case _:
        <default case>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
#another:
while not self.quit:
    # your code

# main
try:
    # your code
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    another.quit = True
    time.sleep(5) # or wait for threading.enumerate() or similar
```

If I want it more robust, say, exit in presence of bugs too:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    another.quit = True
    signal.alarm(5)
    time.sleep(6)
```

A side effect to this is that every block where you `except:` or `except Exception, e:` (which is not something you should do anyway/much) you have to prepend `except KeyboardInterrupt: raise` so that the exception is not "eaten".

Comment: part of your answer will not work on Windows which what the question is about. signal.alarm is not available on Windows

Comment: and FWIW @qarma  ... I would be quite interested in something that works like signal.alarm but on windows

Answer (score -1):

I use this for catching a ctrl-c on windows. In case I'm writing to a pipe or file or what have you.. I want to exit gracefully. Below is a toy example

```
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(signal, frame):    
    print('Process Interrupted!\n\a')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal_handler)

#Rest of your code
```